# Return the rows(Ids) which satisfies and has both the values in IN condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, where-clause, where-in

I have a below `table` with sample data called `Recipes` which acts as a `junction table` between other `2 tables`.

**Query -**

```
select recipeId, IngredientId  from Recipes where IngredientId in (1,31) order by recipeId
```

When i `execute` above `SQL` statement it gives below `Output.` which is fine.

[image]

What changes i have to make in the query to get below highlighted `Output`.

[image]

Now why `6`,`7` & `21`?

As `RecipeIds` `6`, `7` & `21` are the only `Ids` which has `both IngrdientIds` `[i.e. 1,31]`

Comment: What about RecipeID = 6?

Comment: @MJH edited my question please check

Comment: I thought it may be just a typo, but I wanted to make sure you hadn't missed something from the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `group by` clause :

```
select RecipeIds 
from table t
where IngrdientIds in (1, 31)
group by RecipeIds 
having count(distinct IngrdientIds) = 2;
```

You can also use `min()` & `max()` function :

```
having min(IngrdientIds) = 1 and max(IngrdientIds) = 31;
```

Comment: seems like working at my end for the above values `(1,31)`, but will it work for the dynamic conditions in `IN clause`?

Comment: Could you please let me know what is `count(distinct IngrdientIds) = 2`

Comment: @PB-BitWiser. . . It will count unique `IngrdientIds`.

Comment: @PB-BitWiser. . . If you have `IngrdientIds` like `1, 1, 31` then it will count as `2` rather than `3`.